# Pokemon Go crashes on Sony Xperia E1 after safety message pops up?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

Basically the title.

When it loads, a safety message pops up, then when I tap OK it pauses for 5 seconds, then it crashes back to homescreen. I've tried a lot of things, I've reinstalled multiple times. I'm using the **Sony Xperia E1.**

I'm starting to believe that I need a better phone because it can't handle all the tasks. If that's the case is there an alternative to fixing this other than purchasing a phone?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I installed the game on my iPad and then progressed a little, then hopped back onto my phone, and now it works, but it was pointless. I'm getting like 6 FPS.

Time for a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia_E1#Software), the Sony Xperia E1 comes stock loaded with Android 4.3 (Jellybean) The minimum required Android version to run Pokemon Go is Android 4.4 (KitKat). If you haven't updated to 4.4.2 (or your carrier has not pushed out [Sony's Android 4.4.2 update](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2014/08/08/new-sony-software-upgrade-including-android-4-4-kitkat-rolls-for-xperia-e1-and-xperia-e1-dual/) in your area), your phone will be unable to play Pokemon Go.

From Niantic's [Supported Devices](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) page:

> #### Android
>
> - Android 4.4 to Android 6.0.1
>
>   - (Android N will not supported until the official Android release)
> - Preferred resolution of 720x1280 pixels (Not optimized for tablet)
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Intel CPUs are not supported

Comment: This is incorrect. It is 4.4.2, GSM Arena has not updated this.

Comment: @Alaanor - My apologies, I've done some more research and updated my answer accordingly. While it might not help in your case, it's still good info to have in case someone else with an Xperia has the same issue.